# Sqlite trigger in android with an update

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

When I am trying to achieve is a trigger that will update a table when an insert is made that should if the table has the articleId in place already the articleIsLiked should be changed to 0 and if not it should insert the articleId and the articleIsLiked to 1. Currently when I make an insert a new record is made each time I try to run an insert query instead of updating the record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_update
AFTER INSERT ON articlesTable
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO articlesTable ( articleId, articleIsLiked) 
       VALUES(NEW.articleId, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
       articleIsLiked = 0; 
END;
```

**articlesTable**

```
 id PK 
 articleId int  
 articleIsLiked int
```

Comment: Why do you run an INSERT when you actually want an UPDATE?

Comment: That is when you view a new item and try to like it it should insert into the db, but if you try to like it again it should change the previously saved value of `1` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an INSERT into an UPDATE with a trigger.

The easiest way to do this is in your code:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    long c = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "articlesTable",
                                           "articleId = " + id);
    if (c > 0) {
        cv.put("articleIsLiked", 0);
        db.update("articlesTable", cv, ""articleId = " + id, null);
    } else {
        cv.put("articleId", id);
        cv.put("articleIsLiked", 1);
        db.insert("articlesTable", null, cv);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```